# unexpected end of file errors when starting xterm

Tags: console, terminal

I'm getting an `unexpected end of file on line 27` of this script, which I didn't write but appears in my /etc/profile folder and apparently executes to setup environmental variables for my BASH shell console. So everytime I start a new console, I get this error, which is annoying.

Can anyone help me figure out the problem?  There are 2 scripts...both are c-shell scripts (*.csh)

### Here's the first that gives me the first error (libglib2.csh):

```
#! /bin/csh
#
# Description:  This script sets the environment variables G_FILENAME_ENCODING
# and G_BROKEN_FILENAMES for the glib-2.0 library.
#
# G_FILENAME_ENCODING
#       This environment variable can be set to a comma-separated list of
#       character set names.  GLib assumes that filenames are encoded in the
#       first character set from that list rather than in UTF-8.  The special
#       token "@locale" can be used to specify the character set for the
#       current locale.
#
# G_BROKEN_FILENAMES
#       If this environment variable is set, GLib assumes that filenames are
#       in the locale encoding rather than in UTF-8.

# If the LANG you have set contains any form of "UTF", we will guess you are
# using a UTF-8 locale.  Hopefully we're correct.
echo $LANG | grep -iq UTF
if ($status==0) then
  setenv G_FILENAME_ENCODING "@locale"
endif

# It doesn't hurt to export this since G_FILENAME_ENCODING takes priority
# over G_BROKEN_FILENAMES:
setenv G_BROKEN_FILENAMES 1
```

---

### here's the 2nd one, also gives an error (qt4.csh):

```
#! /bin/csh
# Environment path variables for the Qt package:
if (! $?QT4DIR ) then

# It's best to use the generic directory to avoid
# compiling in a version-containing path:
if ( -d /usr/lib/qt ) then
    set path "QT4DIR /usr/lib/qt"
else
    # Find the newest Qt directory and set $QT4DIR to that:
    foreach qtd "/usr/lib/qt-*"
        if (-d $qtd ) then 
            setenv QT4DIR $qtd 
        endif
    end
endif
endif

set path = $path "$QT4DIR /bin"
if ( $?CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH ) then
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH $QT4DIR/include:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
else
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH $QT4DIR/include
endif
exit
```

---

These scripts seem to have corresponding Bourne shell scripts associated with them, but I only get errors from my console telling me that the .csh files have errors (unexpected end of file).  Nothing is reported about the .sh scripts when I start a console terminal window.

I'm new to Unix scripting and shell programming, and I have a feeling there is some minor obscure (to me) formatting mistake somewhere earlier in the scripts.

Comment: Usually end of file errors happen if code is not parsed properly.

Answer (score 0):

These scripts begin with `#!/bin/csh` and not `#!/bin/csh -f` (which is better form) so they will always run *your own* shell startup files (e.g. `.cshrc` or `.tcshrc` in your home directory) every time they are invoked.

With two unrelated scripts having errors the common thing between them is probably your own dot-files.  First add `-f` to the first line of each script to see if this fixes the problem; then look in your own files for syntax errors.